# Android - wrap text view's width does not change when the holder is updated using the payload of the RecycleVview

Tags: android, kotlin

First, please understand that my English is not good. sry...

I have RecyclerView that use ListAdapter, DiffUtil with Payload (use payload to not trigger the change animation)
and holder has ViewGroup and TextView

Item Holder xml

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.pine_template.TextGoneData" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:background="@color/gray_2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llTest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:visibility="@{model.visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#87ceeb"
                    android:text="@{model.text}" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The problem is that if the visibility of the ViewGroup(id.llTest) is changed to View.VISIBLE after View.GONE, the text of the newly set TextView(id.tvText) is entered, but the width does not change.

[before gone text]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtE9i.png)

[after gone text with new text]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9NYO.png)

Is there any way to make the TextView have the correct width?

Instead of using a payload, I set the change animation duration to '0'.
it's do not trigger change animation and apply correct text view's width. (to be precise, can't feel the animation.)
I think this is incorrect.

**UPDATE**

I found a detailed path to reproduce.

1. input string to TextView [12345]
2. set visibilty to gone TextView's parent
3. input less than leghth string like [123]
4. change visibility to visible
5. execute 1~5 by ListAdapter.submitList

Comment: Why are you using nested Linearlayout, you can resolve your issue with also one

Comment: @SurajkaranMeghwanshi thanks for the reply. this source is just sample for reproduce issue.
My app's layout tree is different from sample, is deeper than and text view should gone with other views.